# Comparing value in Access report field to a query using VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I currently have a report that lists steps for various tasks and tracks the revision count. Each page is one task, with all of the steps under it. At the end of the report is a Revision history where it will list what was changed to update the revision count. I have two queries for the report, one to generate the report data and the other to generate the revision history.

What I need to do, is to show which tasks have changes on them. I want to do that by comparing the Task_ID on each report page to the Task_ID found in the revision history query.

I've tried a few varitions of dlookups and dcounts without any luck. Whenever I monitor the code, it keeps treating it as false and will end it.

```
If DLookup("[Task_ID]", "[qry_revision_history_conversions]") = [Reports]![rpt_WI_Book].[Report]![Task] Then
[Reports]![rpt_WI_Book].[Report]![Rev_Change].Visible = False
```

It's probably something really simple I'm missing, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Here's the code I used to make it work.

```
Dim LookupTask As Variant
Dim lngRed As Long, lngYellow As Long, lngWhite As Long
lngRed = RGB(255, 0, 0)
 lngBlack = RGB(0, 0, 0)
 lngYellow = RGB(255, 255, 0)
 lngWhite = RGB(255, 255, 255)

LookupTask = DLookup("[Task_ID]", "[qry_task_check]", [Reports]![rpt_WI_Book].[Report]![Text474])

If LookupTask = [Reports]![rpt_WI_Book].[Report]![Text474] Then
    [Reports]![rpt_WI_Book].[Report]![Text474].BackColor = lngYellow

Else
[Reports]![rpt_WI_Book].[Report]![Text474].BackColor = lngWhite
End If
```

Comment: You have no criteria in your `DLookUp()`, therefore it will always return the first *TaskID* of query. Also, do data types align? Is the subreport control, *Task*, an integer like id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what fields are in your table, but maybe I can assume you're trying to match TaskID to the Report Task field?

From [the DLookup docs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DLookup-Function-8896cb03-e31f-45d1-86db-bed10dca5937?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

*if you don't supply a value for criteria, the DLookup function returns a random value*

Use your criteria inside DLookup and then check for Null:

```
Dim LookupTask as Variant

LookupTask = DLookup("[Task_ID]", "[qry_revision_history_conversions]", "[Task_ID] = " & [Reports]![rpt_WI_Book]![Task])

If Not IsNull(LookupTask) Then
    [Reports]![rpt_WI_Book]![Rev_Change].Visible = False
End If
```

Comment: I tried that code and it didn't help. I should've elaborated further, but the the Task field in the report is generated by a separate query and each section of the report will list each task. The query I am running can have as few as one task id's or multiple depending on if it was recently changed. Because of the that, I only want the image to appear if only the Task ID shows up in qry_revision_history_conversions.

Comment: You're right - you should include these important details in your question

Comment: You were able to get me pointed in the right direction, but I just needed to create an additional query and do some fine touch up and now it's up and running. Plus it also helps to not be suffering a fever while working.

Comment: Good work - you can always post your updated code in your question or in another answer for others to benefit from **EDIT - Hah - you beat me to it!**